# Why count of Collection's docs in MongoDb sharding is decreasing

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a mongo sharding cluster, with 3 shards, and all of operations to this db is `find` or `update`(with upsert=true option). That means the count of collection will keep increasing, but when the count for collection (`db.mycollection.find().count()`) increases to 80000000 or larger, I found that sometimes it's incresing, but sometimes it's decreasing, Why?  I promise that there is no delete action to this db.

I am using `db.myCollection.getShardDistribution()` to show the distribution, and the `shard2` is only 29%, which is less than average.

Here are the trend of count:

```
mongos> db.myCollection.find().count()
84374837
mongos> db.myCollection.find().count()
84375036
mongos> db.myCollection.find().count()
84409281
mongos> db.myCollection.find().count()
84408921
mongos> db.myCollection.find().count()
84407190
mongos> db.myCollection.find().count()
84407173
mongos> db.myCollection.find().count()
84407013
mongos> db.myCollection.find().count()
84406911
```

Comment: `Totals
 data : 53.89GiB docs : 84399594 chunks : 1732
 Shard shard1 contains 35.44% data, 35.78% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 679B
 Shard shard2 contains 29.7% data, 29.51% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 690B
 Shard shard3 contains 34.84% data, 34.69% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 688B`

Comment: I am using `db.myCollection.getShardDistribution()` to show the distribution, shard1:35%, shard2:29%, shard3:36%,  does that have problem?

Answer (score 2):

I'd bet this is sharding in action. This is how it works:

- All documents are broken into virtual chunks
- Chunks can be moved between shards
- When balancer moves a chunk, it

  1) Copies all documents from this chunk to their new shard

  2) Transfers ownership of the chunk to the new shard

  3) **Deletes** documents from the old shard.

Again, this is just a guess, based on information provided. But since you swear there are no deletes in your app, then it must be this.

Comment: I am querying count in mongos, not a single shard. If it's a moving action between shards, the total count will not be decrease.

Comment: Again, "moving" is three-step process.

Comment: The cluster is running for 2 days, but the total count of collection is not increased, remain 84407173